# How to get Django stdout forwarded to Elastic Beanstalk logs?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Django application runs on Elastic Beanstalk, using Amazon Linux 2 platform. My problem is that output to stdout (e.g. print ("hello world") ) is not stored in any log file found in the log bundle.

I just migrated to AL2 from the older Amazon Linux platform. With the legacy platform I did not have issues with logs.

What configuration am I missing?

Comment: Can you check `/var/log/web.stdout.log` file?

Comment: I just noticed that the logs arrive there when I restart the server. Before that they are buffered 'somewhere'.

Comment: Don't know if there is any delay in the log deliver. The best way to check would be to ssh into the EB instance and check from there how it works.

Answer (score 0):

adding PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 as an environment variable did the trick.